# sql alternating column data

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm building a query in sql where I'm collecting information on sales transactions, two of the tables I pull in from are CLIENT_NOTES. One client can have any number of notes, but not visa versa.

Currently my query looks like:

```
SELECT client.name, client.email,..., client_notes.summary AS SUMMARY
FROM CLIENT client
LEFT JOIN CLIENT_NOTES client_notes ON client.CLIENT_ID = client_notes.CLIENT_ID
```

I also want to pull in REFERENCE_NOTES.summary for clients. Again, one client can have any number of reference notes, but not visa versa. But I want to pull the data in such a way that all the client_notes.summary entries show up for a particular client and then the references_notes.summary entries show up for the that same client until moving on to the next client, where both summaries are displayed under the same column named summary.

Is this possible in sql?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this by using UNION ALL. Basically two select statements smashed together. The first gets the client_notes and the second gets reference_notes. Some things to note about UNION is the number and order of columns have to be the same. Data types have to be compatible as well.

```
--Get client_notes
SELECT client.name, client.email,..., client_notes.summary AS SUMMARY
FROM CLIENT client
LEFT JOIN CLIENT_NOTES client_notes ON client.CLIENT_ID = client_notes.CLIENT_ID
UNION ALL
--Get reference_notes
SELECT client.name, client.email,..., reference_notes.summary AS SUMMARY
FROM CLIENT client
LEFT JOIN REFERENCE_NOTES reference_notes ON client.CLIENT_ID = reference_notes.CLIENT_ID
ORDER BY client.name
```